# Chai, Mocha: Identify should assertion

Tags: mocha.js, should.js, chai

I'm using `mocha` and `chai` as assertions.

I have several assertions in my spec:

```
Exp1.should.be.true
Exp2.should.be.true
Exp3.should.be.true
```

If one of them fails mocha writes "expected false to be true". Is there a way to identify them?

With `expect` I can do it:

```
expect(Exp1, 'Exp1').to.be true
```

Is something like this possible with `should`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `should` does not support custom error messages at the moment.

You can create your own helper for setting the message:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should();

// Helper definition - should be in a shared file
chai.use(function(_chai, utils) {
  _chai.Assertion.addMethod('withMessage', function(msg) {
    utils.flag(this, 'message', msg);
  });
});

// Sample usage
it('should fail', function() {
  var Exp1 = false;
  var Exp2 = false;
  Exp1.should.be.withMessage('Exp1').true;
  Exp1.should.withMessage('Exp2').be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the [chai code with respect to should](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/chai.js#L6997) and found that the currently accepted answer is either incorrect or incomplete.

If you read there, you will find that there is indeed a way to include your own custom message in each assertion. The catch is that you may need to change your assertion syntaxes to use `should`'s function calls instead.

```
(1).should.equal(0, 'This should fail');
/****** Output with (I believe) default reporter *****
 * This should fail
 * + expected - actual
 *
 *  -1
 *  +0
 */
```

Note that your output may look different if you are using your own reporter. If you feel so inclined, you could probably wrap `should`'s functions to always include line number in your assertion output.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why they don't simply add which line fired the assertion, but I ran into this exact same problem myself. A colleague who can manuals better than I noted there is a setting for `includeStack` which will give line numbers for assertions.
http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#configure

Since I'm doing a lot of async, I might run my tests in `before` or `beforeEach` and then run a separate `it` for each assertion.