# How to use Should.JS with Chai

Tags: javascript, tdd, bdd, chai, should.js

I would like to use custom error message with Should.JS and while searching for solutions I came across this answer [Apparently should does not support custom error messages at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144078/473923)

Currently I have been using Should.js version 3.3.2 and my code to use it is as follows.

```
var should = require('should');
```

Following the examples found in Chai documentation, I have changed my code to be the following.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
```

Having done so, I now have a bunch of broken tests and chai.should() is the culprit.

I kind of expected that chai.should() was really just a wrapper for Should.js and that it added filters/inteceptors so that you could configure useful extensions but when I inspect the object created by `require('chai').should()` against `require('should')` I notice that they are totally different api's

### Here is some logging Code

```
var chai = require('chai');

var should = chai.should();
l.line('require("chai").should()');
l.inspect(should);
l.line('require("should")');
var shouldOriginal = require('should');
l.inspect(shouldOriginal);
console.log('----------------------------------------');
```

### Log Output

[image: Output]

### Tests are now failing on Should

[image: Tests are now failing on Should]

Please note that my real goal is just adding custom error messages to Should.JS

Comment: It is very bad idea to use both .getters from chai and shouldjs. It is by design in should.js to do not support custom messages (due to multilevel assertions).

Comment: I'm not attempting to use both at once, I'm just demonstrating that the API for Chai.should() is nothing like should.js which seems odd

Comment: chai and should.js developed by different people. It looks pretty ok to have different API and/or different features. You are welcomed to should.js issues or gitter chat (i am should.js maintainer) with such questions.